# using a snippet php in wordpress but my php doesn'work . why?

Tags: php, wordpress

hi i have a snippet for insert php in wordpress but nothing appears.
here my code php

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">         <input type="text" name="nome_utente" placeholder="Nome utente"/><br/>
                <textarea rows="10" cols="100" name="testo_messaggio"></textarea><br/>      <input type="submit" name="tasto_invia" value="Invia"/>     </form> <?php   if (isset($_POST["tasto_invia"]))   {       echo "Ciao " . $_POST["nome_utente"];       echo 'Il tuo messaggio è: "' . $_POST["testo_messaggio"] . '".<br> Grazie per averci contattato.<br>';  }   ?>
```

where I am wrong, please? thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is no syntax, logical or runtime error that I can think of. Are you inserting this snippet in a front-end facing template i.e., page.php or single .php?

It depends where are you adding this snippet and if someone before this snippet is truncating the output. I can help you further if you can share the file name..